# set TableView cell label struct's array

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I've struct with two properties one is `carName` which's type is string and the other one is `carModel` which is an array of strings, I've created `CollectionView` of `carName`'s and after clicking the specific `CollectionView` cell, Main view controller (which is `CollectionView`) goes to the other one which is `TableView` and in that view I want to set labels of `carModel`. here are the pictures for better understanding:[CollectionView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jutk.png)  -> [TableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKaLg.png)
from the last picture you can see that my code doesn't work. expected result:[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utXIa.png). I tried for loop ,switch and case but doesn't seem to work. any solutions?

```swift
struct Cars {
    let carName:String
    let carModel:[String]
}
let cars = [
    Cars(carName: "Mercedes", carModel: ["S Class","A Class", "B Class"]),
    Cars(carName: "BMW", carModel: ["X5","X6","X7"]),
    Cars(carName: "Ford", carModel: ["Fuison","Focus","Mustang"]),
    Cars(carName: "Toyota", carModel: ["Camry", "Corolla"]),
    Cars(carName: "Hyundai", carModel: ["Elantra"])
]
```

```swift
///TableViewCell code
    @IBOutlet var lbl: UILabel!
    func configure(with cars:Cars){
        for i in 0..<cars.carModel{
            lbl.text = cars.carModel[i]    // Error is here
        }
    }
```

```swift
extension ViewController:UICollectionViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "TableViewController") as? TableViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
        a = indexPath.row
        
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        print(indexPath.row)
        cell.configure(with: cars[a])
        return cell
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is wrong approach
first you have set

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cars.count
}
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "TableViewController") as? TableViewController
    vc.carsArray = cars[indexPath.row].carModels
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
           
}
```

you should make a var carsArray on tableviewcontroller like that

```
class TableViewContrller {
  var carsArray:[String] = [] {
     didSet { tableView.reloadData()
    }
  }
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return carsArray.count
  }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    print(indexPath.row)
    cell.configure(with: carsArray[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

Comment: You code returns an error

Comment: what kinda of error ?

Comment: `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Cars'` on the `cell.configure(with: carsArray[indexPath.row])` line

Comment: change the parameter type to String func configure(with: String ) in tableview cell

Comment: `Value of type 'Cars' has no member 'carModels'` and this one on `vc?.carsArray = cars[indexPath.row].carModels
` this line

Comment: or use it directly like remove that line in cellforRow at 
remove : cell.configure(with: carsArray[indexPath.row]) 
with : cell.textLabel.text = carsArray[indexPath.row]

Comment: did you make a variable carsArray on tableViewController ?

Comment: carModels rename it to carModel*

Comment: vc.carsArray = cars[indexPath.row].carModel*

Comment: When I click my `CollectionViewCell` View doesn't change

Comment: can you help please ?

Comment: send me your project at @zeeshan.ahmad1276@gmail.com

Comment: Alright, the project is sent.

Comment: you made a mistake on UITableViewController
UITableViewController already have its own tableView inside why you add ttable and reload it ? 
you just have to reload tableView.reloadData()
in didSet 
bcuz its a tableviewcontroller not a viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Your struct

```
struct Cars {
    let carName:String
    let carModel:[String]
}
```

First ViewController - CollectinViewControler class

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    let cars = [
        Cars(carName: "Mercedes", carModel: ["S Class","A Class", "B Class"]),
        Cars(carName: "BMW", carModel: ["X5","X6","X7"]),
        Cars(carName: "Ford", carModel: ["Fuison","Focus","Mustang"]),
        Cars(carName: "Toyota", carModel: ["Camry", "Corolla"]),
        Cars(carName: "Hyundai", carModel: ["Elantra"])
    ]
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        self.cars.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellid", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! YourCollectionViewCell
        cell.label.text = self.cars[indexPath.row].carName
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TableViewController") as? SecondViewController
        vc?.carModel = self.cars[indexPath.row].carModel
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Your Second Viewcontroller - TableView

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var carModel: [String]?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        self.carModel?.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell") as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.carModel?[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```